# В SharePoint нужно создать несколько списков связанных с одним основным, по условию

Tags: share, sharepoint

Работаю над корпоративным сайтом в SharePoint. Возникла проблема с реализацией проекта согласно которому группа пользователей заполняет некий список с указанием группы пользователей и относящейся к ней информацией. Список есть. Теперь нужно сделать так чтобы каждая группа могла войти только в свою информацию, предполагается для каждой группы свой список (групп не много). Нужно отразить в каждом отдельном списке только относящуюся к нему информацию. Причем чтоб обновлялась она автоматически ( пользователь только открыл, посмотрел, скачал). То есть это может быть возможно не список, а просто отчет како-то.
Паталась реализовать через запросы в ms-Access, после загрузки в сайт связь теряется, с отчетом Access таже история, данные не подгружаются. Возможно можно прописать кодом путь для загрузки?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Это не учебное задание, а конкретная рабочая задача, которую я пыталась реализовать через Access. Поэтому и спрашиваю еще возможные пути для реализации

Comment: Ок. Тогда почитайте вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и попробуйте развернуть свой вопрос. В таком виде довольно высока вероятность того ,что его просто закроют. И заодно добавьте метку Access, только внимательно посмотрите, какая именно Вам нужна: access, ms-access....

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой же вопрос. Все оказалось просто и элементарно. Создала для каждоц группы пользователей свою страничку, со своими доступами, добавила туда приложение мой "Список"- один для всех, и на каждой странице создала свое представление с фильтром по параметраметрам групп. Все работает